# Create a new column with Ratio calculation of 2 merged data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I merged 2 data frames into one on `Username` and converted the values into `float`. I want to create a new column in which it calculates the percentage.

df1:

```
Username total_false_positive

x         10

y         20

z         30

s         40

a         50
```

df2:

```
Username total_tickets

x         20

y         30

z         40

s         50

a         60
```

df3 now is

```
username total_false_positive total_tickets

x            10                  20

y            20                  30

z            30                  40 

s            40                  50

a            50                  60
```

I tried this:

`df3.insert(3, "FPRatio", (df1['total_false_positive']/df2['total_tickets'])*100)`

but the results were messed up.
not sure what I can do to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why the table format didn't show up properly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your dataframes do not align as you did not show the "messed up" part. As you already have `df3` with the correct data I would base the calculation also on `df3` and not on the other to dataframes. Simply replace `df1` and `df2` by `df3` like this:

```
df3.insert(3, "FPRatio", (df3['total_false_positive']/df3['total_tickets'])*100)
```

My output:

```
    username    total_false_positive    total_tickets   FPRatio
0   x   10  20  50.000000
1   y   20  30  66.666667
2   z   30  40  75.000000
3   s   40  50  80.000000
4   a   50  60  83.333333
```